# Sitecore Query - Restrict to context Language (in RSS feeds)?

Tags: multilingual, sitecore-query, rss

I am using Sitecore's RSS feed, which has a field for `Items`.  You can set this field to a Sitecore query to find items within your website to show within your RSS feed.

I have it configured like so:

[image]

This is set to a value like so: `query:/sitecore/content/Brand/home/insights//*[@@templateid='{guid}']`

**The Problem**: when viewing the RSS feed, it appears that items are returned for all language versions.  Is it possible to set the `query:` to be restricted by language?

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer is NO, it cannot handle multiple languages. From the [documention](https://sdn.sitecore.net/upload/sdn5/developer/using%20sitecore%20fast%20query/using%20sitecore%20fast%20query.pdf)

> Sitecore Fast Query does take the context language into account when
>   it checks the value of non-shared fields. The query results therefore
>   include all the items that have one or more language versions that
>   match the query expression.

Also from the [John West blog](https://community.sitecore.net/technical_blogs/b/sitecorejohn_blog/posts/sitecore-query-cheat-sheet)

> Fast query does not account for the context language (results include
>   items with versions that match the query in any language)

Better option would be to switch to Content Search, it will be better for scaling purposes as well.

Comment: Can you switch Sitecore's native RSS to content search?

Comment: His question is regarding `query:`, not `fast:`. Perhaps the answer is the same, but there is a difference.